# Calling javascript functions from android activity

Tags: javascript, android

Is it possible to call a javascript function from java code in Android. Consider the javascript function in a .js file.

```
function calcSum(firstNumber, secondNumber){ 
      return (firstNumber+secondNumber); 
}
```

I want to call this function from my java code and show the result in TextView. I don't want to use WebView.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `WebView`?

Comment: my javascript file contains functions related to mathematical calculation only, so they will be returning some integers or floating point numbers. So, I dont think it will be good to load webview just to show a number.

Comment: Have you considered porting the functionality to your java code? Or do the functions need to be dynamic in some way.

Comment: I may port it in future perhaps, but as of now I am trying to call those functions from java code; as it will help me to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use web view you will need a nother kind of javascript interpreter.  For example Rhino:

http://www.mozilla.org/rhino

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine)